# Docker Windows Container - Cannot reach host defined using --add-host option

Tags: windows, docker, containers

I started a docker container using the --add-host option to allow the container to access another machine in the network.

```
C:\Development\YADAMU>docker run --name YADAMU-01 --network YADAMU-NET --storage-opt "size="100GB""  --memory "4g" -v C:\SHARED:C:\YADAMU\mnt --add-host="VRTCA23-01:192.168.1.236" --add-host="VRTCA10-01:192.168.1.236" --add-host="azure-01:192.168.1.236" --add-host="minio-01:192.168.1.236" -e YADAMU_TEST_NAME=everything -e TESTNAME=mssql2014TestSuite -d yadamu/regression:latest
85851c4762ef9ceaeac5e493e132e59c7627115a4fe249767350ae41876ffc81
```

As you can see I can ping the host's IP address from within the container, but I cannot ping it by name. I can ping other containers running on the same machine. ORA1903-01 is a container running on the same host and using the same network as YADAMU-01.

```
C:\Development\YADAMU>docker exec -it YADAMU-01 cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.20348.2031]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\YADAMU>ping VRTCA23-01
Ping request could not find host VRTCA23-01. Please check the name and try again.

C:\YADAMU>ping 192.168.1.236

Pinging 192.168.1.236 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.236: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=63
Reply from 192.168.1.236: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=63
Reply from 192.168.1.236: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=63
Reply from 192.168.1.236: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=63

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.236:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 1ms, Average = 0ms

C:\YADAMU>

C:\YADAMU>ping ORA1903-01

Pinging ORA1903-01 [172.26.34.100] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.26.34.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.26.34.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 172.26.34.100: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 172.26.34.100:
    Packets: Sent = 3, Received = 3, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms

C:\YADAMU>exit
```

The hosts appear to have been correctly added to the container

```
C:\Development\YADAMU>docker container inspect YADAMU-01
[
    {
        "Id": "85851c4762ef9ceaeac5e493e132e59c7627115a4fe249767350ae41876ffc81",
        "Created": "2023-10-19T16:54:33.7214514Z",
        "Path": "powershell",
        "Args": [
            "c:\\YADAMU\\bin\\chooseTest.ps1"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 1668,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-10-19T16:54:35.7668862Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:4789c9b11c22819fc7f0c304162702c3ace3f8ccf615cd7be83d0fe5437ead32",
        "ResolvConfPath": "",
        "HostnamePath": "",
        "HostsPath": "",
        "LogPath": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\containers\\85851c4762ef9ceaeac5e493e132e59c7627115a4fe249767350ae41876ffc81\\85851c4762ef9ceaeac5e493e132e59c7627115a4fe249767350ae41876ffc81-json.log",
        "Name": "/YADAMU-01",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "windowsfilter",
        "Platform": "windows",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "C:\\SHARED:C:\\YADAMU\\mnt"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "YADAMU-NET",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                59,
                198
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": [
                "VRTCA23-01:192.168.1.236",
                "VRTCA10-01:192.168.1.236",
                "azure-01:192.168.1.236",
                "minio-01:192.168.1.236"
            ],
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "StorageOpt": {
                "size": "100GB"
            },
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 0,
            "Isolation": "hyperv",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 4294967296,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": null,
            "ReadonlyPaths": null
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "dir": "C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\85851c4762ef9ceaeac5e493e132e59c7627115a4fe249767350ae41876ffc81"
            },
            "Name": "windowsfilter"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "c:\\shared",
                "Destination": "c:\\yadamu\\mnt",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "85851c4762ef",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "YADAMU_TEST_NAME=everything",
                "TESTNAME=mssql2014TestSuite",
                "TNS_ADMIN=c:\\YADAMU",
                "YADAMU_PASSPHRASE=yabasc"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "yadamu/regression:latest",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "C:\\YADAMU",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "powershell",
                "c:\\YADAMU\\bin\\chooseTest.ps1"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "85851c4762ef9ceaeac5e493e132e59c7627115a4fe249767350ae41876ffc81",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "85851c4762ef9ceaeac5e493e132e59c7627115a4fe249767350ae41876ffc81",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "YADAMU-NET": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "85851c4762ef"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "c5fe376d9dedbaae12c53564bfb34e294e7a99cd14d6d06e0f6d7d865453c48f",
                    "EndpointID": "5d2bb19f8b0f4c26d8e2d44c9665f9079170c3b11d6d4216378441cf628fc911",
                    "Gateway": "172.26.32.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.26.34.215",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "00:15:5d:69:8a:fa",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]

C:\Development\YADAMU>
```

I have been able to use the same technique with Linux containers without problem.